# show there isn't a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ of $\{f_n\}$ so that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} f_{n_k}(x)$ always exists

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

> Suppose that $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ so that $\int_0^1 f_m(x) f_n(x)dx = \begin{cases} 1,\text{ if $n=m$}\\
> 0,\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$ and $\sup\{|f_n(x)| : x\in [0,1]$ and $n=1,2,\cdots\} < \infty.$

> Prove that there does not exist a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ of $\{f_n\}$ so that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} f_{n_k}(x)$ exists for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Suppose there did, and define $f(x)=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} f_{n_k}(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. First, I think that if $\int_0^1 g(x)f(x)dx = 0$ for all functions $g\in L^2[0,1]$ (i.e. integrable functions under the 2-norm), then $f$ must be zero almost everywhere, but I'm not sure how to show this. Also, by the Dominated convergence theorem, since $\sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f_m(x)||f_{n_k}(x)| <\infty$ for all $m,n_k$, we have that $0=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \int_0^1 f_m(x) f(x)dx$ for all m. And similarly, $1= \lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \int_0^1 f_{n_k}^2(x)dx = \int_0^1 f(x)^2 dx$, which yields a contradiction provided $f(x)$ is zero almost everywhere. Can I assume that the sequence $(f_m)$ includes all elements in $L^2[0,1]$ by adding elements to the sequence if necessary? And if so, how would one justify that all these elements would still satisfy the properties of the original sequence $(f_n)$.

Comment: $\|f_n-f_m\|_2=\sqrt 2$

Comment: Matematleta's comment plus dominated convergence will do. (by assumption, your sequence is uniformly bounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $f_{n_k}(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x$ and $|f_n(x)|\le M$ for all $n$ and $x.$  Hence $|f(x)|\le M.$

By the dominated convergence theorem we get
$$\int\limits_0^1f(x)^2\,dx=\lim_{k\to \infty}
\int\limits_0^1f(x)f_{n_k}(x)\,dx$$ Moreover for any fixed $k$ we have
$$\int\limits_0^1f(x)f_{n_k}(x)\,dx\\ =\lim_{l\to \infty} \int\limits_0^1f_{n_l}(x)f_{n_k}(x)\,dx=0$$
Thus $$\int\limits_0^1f(x)^2\,dx=0,$$ On the other hand $$0=\int\limits_0^1f(x)^2\,dx=\lim_{k\to \infty}\int\limits_0^1f_{n_k}(x)^2\,dx=1$$ a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1).